# Is it possible to change the passed query parameter "next" for social login

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

When [linking accounts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking) to fb messenger, fb calls the passed URI for login with a query parameter `redirect_uri` and a `CALLBACK_URL`. A redirect, to `redirect_uri`, with an `authorization_code` if login succeeds must be performed.

If I want to perform the login using social login an issue appears related to what is explained [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/670) . The OAUTH handshake is done respecting the next parameter.

Where it's advisable to create a next parameter reflecting `redirect_uri` such that the redirection takes place and doesn't disrupt all this great package.

If I wait to reach `get_login_redirect_url` the parameter is already dropped when logging in. If it's logged it will be available for the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

By the `social_auth` app you can append `next` parameter to destination site login redirect url and user after successful login redirect automatically, But when using `all_auth` app you must override the `account/signup.html` and add a code similar below to this template:

```
{% if redirect_field_value %}
<input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
{% endif %}
```